# Scalable side scroll trouble

Tags: html, css

I want to create a horizontal scrolling image panel that consists of large images with a max height of 800px. When the browser is resized I want the entire selection of images to get smaller/bigger according to the size of the browser window. I want the top of the images to hang 200px at the top with a 30px margin at the left (when page is loaded) and 30px at the bottom.

I am really new to this so any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated

The HTML looks like this so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Dean Pauley — Recent work</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="infoleft">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Dean Pauley</a></li>
                <li>Graphic Design</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="inforight">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="images">
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The css:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

#infoleft { 
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:0px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
}

#infoleft ul {
    height:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#infoleft ul li { 
    display: inline; 
    padding: 30px;
}       

#inforight {    
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    right:30px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
}

#inforight ul {
    height:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#images {
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    bottom:30px;
    top:200px;
    width:25000px;
    height:800px;
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}

img {
    padding:10px;
}   

a {
    text-decoration:none; color:#000;
}

a:hover {
    color:#0080ff;
}
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?
Many thanks in adavnce

**EDIT**

[image: On page load]

[image: On scroll]

[image: On 75% decrease window]

On page load

On scroll

On 75% decrease window

Comment: do you want these images to fit within the screen or is it OK to have scroll bars on the browser window?

Comment: @Zack Macomber I would like to scroll to the right to view the images but the height should adjust itself accordingly so that there is always 200px above the images and 30px below, I hope that makes sense

Comment: I think you've explained this well, but I'm just not seeing it...is there anyway you could show screenshot mockups of what you'd like to have?  If you could make a couple of simple JPEGs that show what the page should look like full screen and then what it should look like when the browser is resized by 50%, that would be helpful (at least for me).

Comment: @Zack Macomber I have 3 screenshots, how should I send them to you?

Comment: Could you add them to your question through an edit?  When I edit, I usually put a "<b>EDIT</b>" marking below whatever I've already posted and then post the new content below that...

Comment: Dean - did what I propose work for you? Or, did you decide to go another direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the image-related size measurements to % rather than px. That way the size of your images, paddings, margins, etc. will change with the size of the browser window although the proportions will stay the same.

example: img {width:80%; height:60%; etc.}

**edit**

Using part of Zack's answer, I would change your css img rule to:

`img {
    padding:10px;
    width:3.799;
    height:100%;
}`

That will give you an image that adjusts with the browser window size.
However you will need to use percents (%) to adjust your positioning rules (i.e. left, top, padding, margin, etc.) to keep all proportions the same.

**Note**

At this point I am only adjusting the example, so for the record Zack's design is more efficient, and would be better if the look satisfies you.

Comment: Could you possibly show an example in relation to the code above?

Comment: sure, but before I check what I have and post it, did you really mean to put a width of 25000px on you #images?

Comment: there will be alot more projects added. Altogether they probably wont take up as much as that though

Comment: ok, so that was just an example. I will post the code revisions I would make shortly.

Comment: Zack effectively adjusted the elements I was trying to reach in a round about way, so this was a learning experience for me too. Thanks Zack!

Comment: @SamStar - And Zack adjusted those elements based on what he's learned from reading through many SOF posts...I learned to effectively use the display, overflow and white-space portions based on things I've read at SOF.  This is a wonderful site that I constantly consult for good information that I use in the workplace.  It's great to pass it on and see another learn it too.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like these changes to your CSS for the "#images" and "img" sections...

```
#images {
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    bottom:30px;
    top:200px;
    border: 2px ridge gray;
    width: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

img {
    padding:10px;
    width:50%;
    height:95%;
}
```

You can play around with those values but you should get a horizontally scrolling image section that changes on resizing the window...

You can take the gray border off if you'd like - I was just using it for testing...

**EDIT**

Uploaded a code sample with absolute positioning instead of relative as that keeps the image section 30px off the bottom...